# (C++) Doubly Linked List Template - Access Problems

Tags: c++, templates, doubly-linked-list

I am very new to C++ templates. I am currently working on a project where I need to implement a Doubly Linked List using a template. Here is currently what I have so far:

```
template<class ItemType>
class SortedList
{
public:
   SortedList();
   ~SortedList();
   bool Insert (ItemType toAdd);
   bool Delete (ItemType toDelete);
   void Print();

private:
   SortedList ( const SortedList & copyFrom );
   SortedList & operator= ( const SortedList & assignFrom );

   struct Node
   {
      Node ( ItemType item, Node * p = NULL, Node * n = NULL )
      { data = item; prev = p; next = n; }
      ItemType data;
      Node * prev, * next;
   };
   Node * list;
};

template<class ItemType>
SortedList<ItemType>::SortedList()
{
   list == NULL;
}

template<class ItemType>
SortedList<ItemType>::~SortedList()
{
   Node * curr = list;
   while ( curr != NULL )
   {
      Node * tempNext = curr->next;
      delete current;
      current = tempNext;
   }
}
```

However, in my destructor for example, why can't I access the node elements? The code that is inside that method right now compiled, but does not throw errors. However if I try to use -> on curr, next or prev do not appear. Why do I not have access to these? I feel like I am missing something very obvious here to get started.

Also, how can I initialize list == NULL in the function head, instead of doing it outside of the class?

Comment: There's a typo in the constructor. It should be list = NULL; You don't use == to initialize, but to compare.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't know why it compiles, but you are using

`delete current;
current = tempNext;`

Instead of:

```
delete curr;
curr = tempNext;
```

2. Use inline initializer syntax:

`class SortedList
{
public:
   SortedList()
   :
        list(nullptr)
   { }`

3. Use the same syntax to initialize Node (it's more optimal)

Comment: I can add literally anything to my functions and it will successfully compile. That is why I know I have a problem. I added the line "akasmdkamskdm" and it still builds. If I use -> on curr, IntelliSense just says "no members available"

Comment: Remember: templates aren't compiled unless instantiated. You have to have a `SortedList<int> list;` or equivalent somewhere in a compiled cpp (like your main.cpp)

Comment: Alright, I did that, and during build time it will show the error. However, IntelliSense does not show red lines on incorrect statements (I assume this is because of the same reason?)

Although that still does not solve my problem with using ->